# Условие про одинаковый логин

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма, через которую меняю логин, но если такой логин уже есть и написать его снова у newusername, то в БД будет два одинаковых логина, почему закомментируемое условие не работает?

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
protect_page();
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array(
        'username',
        'newusername'
    );
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'поля со звездочкой обязательны';
            break 1;
        }
        if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === ($_POST['newusername'])) {
            $errors[] = 'этот логин \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' используется'; // условие которое должно выводить ошибку и не обновлять логин в БД если такой есть
        }
    }
}

?>
   <h1>пользователи!</h1>
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['newusername'])) {
    $username    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $newusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newusername']);
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `username` = '$newusername' WHERE `username` = '$username'");
}
$ath = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `type`=0");
if ($ath) {
    // Определяем таблицу и заголовок
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><td>user_id</td><td>логин</td><td>пароль</td><td>имя</td><td>email</td></tr>";
    // Так как запрос возвращает несколько строк, применяем цикл
    while ($author = mysql_fetch_array($ath)) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $author['user_id'] . " </td><td>" . $author['username'] . " </td><td>" . $author['password'] . "
            &nbsp </td><td>" . $author['first_name'] . " </td><td>" . $author['email'] . "
            &nbsp </td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "<p><b>Error: " . mysql_error() . "</b><p>";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

файл verify.php (проверка логина и изменение)

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$new_name = $_POST['new_name'];

if(strlen($username) == 0 || $new_name == 0){echo "Поля со звездочками обязательны";exit;}
if($username == $new_name){echo "Новый логин должен отличаться от старого!";exit;}
if(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`username`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$new_name'"),0) == 1){echo "Пользователь с таким именем уже существует!";exit;}

mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `username` = '$new_name' WHERE `username` = '$username'");
echo 'Успешно измененно';
?>
```

Comment: так оно вообще ничего не меняет

Comment: названия таблиц и прочее под себя измените

Comment: нет так оно вообще ничего не пишет и не изменяет, даже после поправки таблиц и переменных в коде как надо! echo "Новый логин должен отличаться от старого!"; не от старого а новый не должен быть такой какой в таблице уже есть

Comment: ну от старого же он тоже должен отличаться, ведь бессмысленная нагрузка на сервер не есть хорошо

Comment: попробуйте вывести сам запрос и ввести вручную

Comment: да делал уже запросы, код уже рабочий, но почему то выводит ошибку дважды, а когда заполняю правильно один раз, какое то недоразумение

Answer (score 0):

Что за неописанная функция user_exists?

Comment: проверяет существует ли такой логин

Comment: Проблемка-то в ней :)
Кидай её сюда.

Comment: может дело в функции user_exists?

Comment: нет не в ней, на регистрации же она работает там правда такое условие if (user_exists($_POST['username'])===true) {
$errors[]='логин \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' занят';
} но если я здесь так сделаю, оно просто пишет что дожно писать но но все равно в БД изменяет логин!

Comment: === TRUE, а у вас  === ($_POST['newusername'])

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то user_exists просто проверяет существует этот юзер или нет. Тогда на кой чёрт проверять на существование текущего логина? Условие должно быть таким: user_exists($_POST['newusername'])

Comment: Тогда нужна сама функция user_exists.

Comment: Нужно изначально сделать условие if(user_exists($_POST['newusername'])), под ним сделать break, и если пользователь, на ник которого мы меняем, уже существует, то меняться не должно.

Comment: if(user_exists($_POST['newusername'])){
break;
}
все равно меняет((( уже не знаю что делать все перепробывал

Comment: сделать проверку логина на отдельной странице.

Comment: сделал проверку в отдельном файле, там все норально, но что бы здесь это значило?